# Format Doctrine SubQuery in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I Have this query :

```
$qb->select("
    tab.product
    ,round(
        (               
            SELECT COUNT( tab2.price )

            FROM Application\Entity\PSRespostas tab2 

            WHERE 
                tab.key = tab2.codkey 
            )
    ,2) as GridPercent
");
```

- But when i execute it occurs the error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 266: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

I tried Without the **ROUND** or any function it works, but i need to do it by ***SQL query***.

it occurs with anyone ? , ask if need more information for the query. :(

***obs.:*** i can't do it on **Join** because the query does some **Groups** **By** and more complex functions that do not permit me to use anything else but a SubQuery

Comment: Could you put the complete query? I would be missing the 'from' for the table  tab.

Comment: Can you explain the relation between tab and tab2 and what result you are expecting

Comment: You cannot put a subquery like that in DQL.

Comment: What is the reason that you absolutely have to do the rounding by SQL and can't do it at the PHP end after retrieving the result?